# Spark : Tasks are not getting parallalized to all executors

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, bigdata, spark-streaming

I have a Spark Streaming application converts the DStream to DataFrame and sends it to and API. The response DataFrame from the API is written to HDFS. I have noticed that the tasks in HDFS write job is not being distributed across the clusters properly.
This is the [executors tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMw6D.jpg) from Spark UI.
Below is the `spark-submit` config:

```
--num-executors 16 \
--executor-memory 11888M \
--executor-cores 5 \
--driver-memory 12G \
```

I'm streaming almost 40 messages every 3 seconds.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Could you add the code? How do you 'send' a `DataFrame` to an API?